# Trigger ON DELETE using MariaDB

Tags: sql, database, triggers, mariadb

I have two tables 'topic' and 'answer':

Table 1-> **topic**

```
+-----+------------+
+  id +   name     +
+=====+============+
+  17 +  question1 +
+-----+------------+
+  18 +  question2 +
+-----+------------+
```

Table 2 -> **answer**

```
+----+---------+----------+
+ id + idtopic +   val    +
+----+---------+----------+
+  1 +  17     +  anwer1  +
+----+---------+----------+
+  2 +  18     +  answer2 +
+----+---------+----------+
```

I'm simply trying to create a trigger to delete items from table 'answer', when deleting items from table 'topic'.
If tried this code, but there is problem with MariaDB syntax I think:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_answer AFTER DELETE on topic
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM answer
    WHERE answer.idtopic = topic.id;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version that will work.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER delete_answer AFTER DELETE on topic
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM answer
    WHERE answer.idtopic = OLD.id;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OLD` keyword to refer to the current row in topic that is being deleted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_answer AFTER DELETE on topic
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM answer
    WHERE answer.idtopic = OLD.id;
END
```

However, I wonder why you're writing a trigger instead of using a foreign key with cascading delete. Are you not using InnoDB for this table?

Comment: This is what I've got using the solution above: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

Comment: Did you set the `DELIMITER`? See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delimiters-in-the-mysql-client/